# How to style a “choose file” button using CSS only

Tags: html, css

I want to try design this :

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

What I want: I want change its color, also change its size...

Comment: can you more specific?what is your expected design?what you want to change

Answer (score 12, accepted):

File type is a native element henceforth you cant change it's appearance. Instead you can hide at the back of some element.

```
<div>
  Choose File
 <input type="file" class="hide_file">
</div>

 div{
  padding:5px 10px;
  background:#00ad2d;
  border:1px solid #00ad2d;
  position:relative;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:2px;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer
}
.hide_file {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Refer [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sqm5puzs/)

Comment: hi, i want to change only choose file button.... but ur method effect on other field also.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use **`::-webkit-file-upload-button`** in css and style your Choose file button.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sample

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/mxq9R/`
```

to change style of input files.

Comment: look at css box, this button is a picture, you can download and edit this picture and replace with orginal to change your font color

Answer (score 2):

```
input[type='file']{
  color:blue;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

Comment: This styles the area behind and around the system button, not the button itself.